# Reemplazar letra por otra sin discriminar mayúsculas o minúsculas

Tags: java

```
Scanner leerFrases= new Scanner (System.in);


String frase;
String letra;
String letraReemplazada;

System.out.print("ingrese una frase:");
frase = leerFrases.nextLine();
System.out.print("ingrese letra que desea reemplazar:");
letra = leerFrases.nextLine();
System.out.print ("ingrese letra por la que sera reemplazada:");
letraReemplazada = leerFrases.nextLine();   


frase = frase.replace(letra, letraReemplazada);
System.out.print(frase);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiene dos posibles opciones , usando `regex` para esto debe emplear [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```
frase = frase.replaceAll("(?i)"+letra, letraReemplazada);
```

O convirtiendo antes la cadena y lo que se va a reemplazar a minúsculas.

```
frase = frase.toLowerCase().replace(letra.toLowerCase(), letraReemplazada);
```

Comment: gracias me funciono super

Comment: Detalle: conviene agregar el modificador [**`u`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) para que también funcione con letras con diacríticos (vocales con acentos, `ñ`, ...). O sea, `"(?iu)"+letra`.

Answer (score 0):

Usando regex

```
frase = frase.replace("(?i)"+letra, letraReemplazada);
```

Comment: Debería ser `String.replaceAll()` en vez de `String.replace()`... Y un detalle: conviene agregar el modificador [**`u`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) para que también funcione con letras con diacríticos (vocales con acentos, `ñ`, ...). O sea, `"(?iu)"+letra`.